# SQL Server Syntax Error on PIVOT

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Can anyone please help me with the PIVOT table syntax error as I am using this for the First time.

```
DECLARE @sql AS varchar(max)<br/>
DECLARE @pivot_list AS varchar(max) <br/>
DECLARE @select_list AS varchar(max) <br/>

SELECT @pivot_list = COALESCE(@pivot_list + ', ', '') + '[' + CONVERT(varchar,    STATE_NAME) + ']'<br/>
      ,@select_list = COALESCE(@select_list + ', ', '') + '[' + CONVERT(varchar, STATE_NAME) + '] AS [' + CONVERT(varchar, STATE_NAME) + ']'
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT name as STATE_NAME
    FROM k12_dms_states
) AS PIVOT_CODES

SET @sql = '
 SELECT COUNT(k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.id)  as total_count 
,k12_dms_job_titles.title as job_title,' + @select_list + '
FROM k12_dms_institution_master 
INNER JOIN k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles ON k12_dms_institution_master.id = k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.inst_id 
INNER JOIN k12_dms_job_titles ON k12_dms_job_titles.id = k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.job_title_id 
GROUP BY k12_dms_job_titles.title
PIVOT (
total_count
FOR STATE_NAME IN (
    ' + @pivot_list + '
)
) AS pvt
 '

  PRINT @sql

  EXEC (@sql)
```

I am getting this error: -

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PIVOT'.

Answer (score 1):

`PIVOT` belongs in the [`FROM` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634%28v=sql.110%29.aspx). It needs to occur before any `GROUP BY` clause.

(Further edits based on commenting, to try to correct):

```
SET @sql = '
 SELECT 
k12_dms_job_titles.title as job_title,' + @select_list + '
FROM k12_dms_institution_master 
INNER JOIN k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles ON k12_dms_institution_master.id = k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.inst_id 
INNER JOIN k12_dms_job_titles ON k12_dms_job_titles.id = k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.job_title_id 
PIVOT (
COUNT(k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.id)
FOR STATE_NAME IN (
    ' + @pivot_list + '
)
) AS pvt
 '
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to get the count of Job titles per state.That's why I added group by.Please advise.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but I am getting this error after using the above query-- Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.

Comment: @user1163513 - that's why the `PIVOT` clause is defined around an aggregate function. Try removing `COUNT` from your `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY` clause, and putting `COUNT(k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.id)` where you currently have `total_count` in your `PIVOT`.

Comment: @user1163513 - I've tried to edit in a change - but you have to understand it's tricky when I don't have access to *your* tables and data.